# Microsoft visual C++ backwards compatibility

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, backwards-compatibility

Consider a C++ API defined as a series of `__options(declexport/import)` classes.

Further, assume that the caller is never permitted to call the ordinary `operator new(size_t)` on these classes. Either a static factory method does the new-ing or there is a class-specific  `operator new`. And ditto marks on the delete size as needed (frequently just a virtual destructor).

Now, if you compile and link a DLL and an IMPLIB of with the tools from VS2010, can you hand that implib and DLL to a user of VS2005 and expect it to work?

MFC is not involved here at all.

I'd be particularly grateful to any reference to any relatively formal Microsoft statement on the subject.

Comment: What was the result of your testing to see if it works?

Comment: Simple cases work. Yawn.

Comment: Then that's great!  It sounds like you did everything right.

Comment: Not to me it doesn't. I'm concerned that either (a) some obscure exception case will explode, or (b) MS reserves the right to pull the rug out from under me. So I'm hoping to find that someone else has been here before me or that there really is a clear 'official' statement of all this.

Comment: My answer remains the same:  don't pass in types that are version-specific implementations.  This list is most easily found by looking at the output of the exports of `MSVC100P.DLL`.

Comment: @suj, it's not easy to test all the exception paths, and, based on sorry experiences with gcc/g++, I'm suspicious that a throw from vs(n) and a catch in vs(n-x) may result in a mess but only in some condition that I can't predict.

Comment: You never, EVER leak exceptions across a DLL boundary.  That way lies total madness.

Answer (score 2):

So long as the name mangling on the C++ API is identical (they are), and does not use STL-type specific parameters, such as `basic_string` or `std::map`, whose implementation may have changed between releases of the compiler (and they have), then it should just work.

Of course, you'll want to make sure you either compiled your DLL using `/MT` mode (static linked runtimes), or include the redistributables for VS2010 runtimes with your supplied libraries and link targets.

*EDIT*: Expanding on "don't pass in types that have version-specific implementations".  A partial list is most easily found by looking at the output of the exports of `MSVC100P.DLL`.

```
cd %VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.CRT
DUMPBIN /exports MSVCP100.DLL
```

The next issue will be header-only implementations of things like `map` or `set` which have changed under the hood between versions of the compiler.

This is why it's highly recommended that only scalar types be passed across boundaries between memory arenas.  And thus, simple tests will pass, and be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned if you have used MFC to create the DLL's .If you have, regular DLL's should work , but I dont think extension shall work as the latter links to the MFC dlls .I am including links for your reference.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c4017

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/MFC/Q_20385543.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26h8x9sy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

**EDIT**
If its a normal DLL, there should not be any problem.Also depends on the linkage type.

Comment: There's no MFC (and, in fact, no GUI at all) in the picture here, so this doesn't address the question at hand.